# Heroku Procfile not finding web process

Tags: python, flask, heroku

I am trying to launch a server on Heroku using Flask and Gunicorn. I have a Procfile which I have both tried creating using `echo "web: gunicorn annallAPI:app" > Procfile`
and with adding the line to a Procfile in vs code. Still everytime I get:

`remote: -----> Discovering process types remote:        Procfile declares types -> (none)`

I have seen problems point to the wrong name, f.x. if it is ProcFile and another pointing to the incorrect encoding, saying it needs to be UTF-8. I have the correct name and I can't convert to UTF-8 because the original_charset has UTF-8.

The build succeeds and then if I make a request to the server, it of course fails. For the record, I am using an M1 Mac.
The error I get in the Heroku log is:

`at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/" host=xxx-api.herokuapp.com request_id=65f19b67-87a1-46bf-84f4-20f4ab36e85b fwd="130.208.240.12" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https`
I tried doing `heroku ps:scale web=1` to start a web process which I don't think should work if the Procfile doesn't have a set web process. It gave me the error:

`Scaling dynos... ! ▸    Couldn't find that process type (web).`

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure that you have created `requirements.txt` which lists out all libraries including `gunicorn`
2. Create Procfile - this file basically has no extension and contains web: `gunicorn yourwsginame:app`
   Personally, I recommend you create this file manually and edit it using a text editor

Comment: 1.I have that. 2. I don't have an extension. I can try doing it in a text editor.

Comment: Now it got the Procfile type -> web. The only thing I did was delete the app and start again. Heroku seems extremely fickle.

Comment: This has nothing at all to do with `requirements.txt`.